# sendmail and domain issue

Tags: sendmail

I am relatively new to sendmail. When I tried to send mail, I got the following in my log:

```
sendmail[3660]: My unqualified host name (DynusT) unknown; sleeping for retry
sendmail[3660]: unable to qualify my own domain name (DynusT) -- using short name
```

I did some research on the net and it seems that it has to do with the hostname, so here's my etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 DynusT.local. DynusT
50.56.81.42 domain1.com
50.56.81.42 domain2.com
```

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking into adjusting the config on one of my sendmail servers today and bumped into [this](http://www.linuxselfhelp.com/quick/sendmail.html) article. After following it, it did the trick for me. I had a similar issue.

Comment: mind sharing your var/hosts? might help me fix this issue

Comment: # Do not remove the following line, or various programs
# that require network functionality will fail.
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain   localhost
::1     localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
10.1.6.1        servername        servername.domain.loc.

Comment: You should be looking into your sendmail config as a first step, I would suggest.

Comment: I changed it to 127.0.0.1 mydomain localhost and it works... not sure why mine doesn't work with 127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost... any ide?

Comment: The reason is probably because in sendmail config you have localhost.localdomain define. Google - "sendmail linux config"

Comment: Here is the link: http://www.linuxselfhelp.com/quick/sendmail.html